# Koa listening port encounters an unknown error

Tags: node.js, koa

When I use koa to monitor 3000, the following error occurs, but no error message is provided. Can you give me an idea to solve the problem.

```
Error: listen UNKNOWN: unknown error 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
    at Application.listen (D:\文档\Back-end-development\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:82:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\文档\Back-end-development\sls.js:42:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  errno: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full sample code of how you are spinning up your server?

Comment: I try to simply reproduce this error. But when I create a new project and rewrite the same code, this error disappears. But I still get this error when I run the original project. Maybe there is a problem with package dependencies? I'm not sure either, but at the moment I solved the problem by creating a new project and refactoring, sorry for not being able to provide the code.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets?